# Manifold exists in and of itself

Tags: soft-question, manifolds, philosophy

I am reading *Shape of Space* by Weeks. The author gives a philosophical comment:

> Even if the universe connects up with itself in funny ways (if it's a three-torus, for example), this *doesn't* mean that it curves around in some four-dimensional space. The essence of the intrinsic point of view is that a manifold exists in and of itself, and needn't lie in any higher-dimensional space.

What exactly does this mean? I have learned what a differentiable manifold is in differential geometry, but I do not think this knowledge is necessary in understanding this comment. Sorry if this comment is too philosophical. I would appreciate intuitive answers.

Comment: abstract manifolds aren't necessarily embeddable in a space. For smooth manifolds, Whitney's embedding theorem tells us every smooth manifold of dimension n is embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.
However, complex manifolds cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ for any $n$, unless they are a point.

Comment: The passage means exactly what is says: One should think of the universe as an abstract manifold rather than a submanifold of another space of higher dimension. The main problem with the passage however that it ignores the space-time which is (traditionally) a 4-dimensional Lorentzian manifold.

Comment: @UnexpectedExpectation Closed complex submanifolds of $\mathbb{C}^n$ are called Stein manifolds and there are plenty of them. Btw. an easy example is an embedding of proper complex linear subspace in $\mathbb{C}^n$ other example is any smooth planar affine algebraic curve for example $y^2 = x^3 + x$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: @Slug:. Perhaps UnexpectedExpectation was implicitly assuming "compact" somewhere.